# Creating OpenGL 4.3 window fails with GLFW3

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I set up a minimal application to open a blank window with GLFW3:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void glfwErrorCallback(int error, const char *description)
{
   std::cerr << "GLFW error " << error << ": " << description << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   GLFWwindow* window;
   glfwSetErrorCallback(glfwErrorCallback);

   if(!glfwInit())
   {
      std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLFW...\n";
      return -1;
   }

   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
   glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

   window = glfwCreateWindow(1024, 768, "GLFW window", NULL, NULL);
   if(!window)
   {
      std::cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window...\n";
      glfwTerminate();
      return -1;
   }

   glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
   if (glewInit())
   {
      std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW...\n";
      glfwTerminate();
      return -1;
   }

   glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

   while (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
   {
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
      glfwPollEvents();
   }

   glfwTerminate();
   return 0;
}
```

It results in the following error:

> GLFW error 65540: Context profiles only exist for OpenGL version 3.2 and above
>   Failed to open GLFW window...

The application is run on Linux with Bumblebee's `optirun`. The code works when using freeglut instead of GLFW. What is wrong with the code that results in the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### This is pretty simple:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4); // Major = 4
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // Major was 4, now it is 3.

// Minor = ???   [Something < 2]
```

You need to use `glfwWindowHint (GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);` instead for the second hint.

Comment: Now I feel like down-voting my own question... Thanks, I guess I would have never found it! It still fails though, just without an error. (Even if I remove all window hints and run it without optirun)

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with using glew: after removing it, the example works. Doesn't have anything to do with this question though.

Comment: Well, if you have a core profile context, when using GLEW, you need to set `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` before calling `glewInit (...)`. That could be related...

Comment: Thanks again, I forgot to copy that line into the example and didn't notice as it never reached that line. The problem is the `;` after `if(!window)` (check the edit log). I should really go to bed.

Comment: I had this issue with SuperBible 6th edition's examples. Major version can be changed in `sb6.h` file.